# replacing certain characters in string REGEX

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am trying to replace some characters that occur only inside parentheses, here are the patterns in which I need the characters to be replaced:

Z should be turned into boolean

J should be replaced by short

L should be replaced by long

I should be replaced by int

S should be replaced by string

B should be replaced by byte

Here are some examples of how my regular expression should behave:

INPUT: net.sourceforge.ganttproject.shape.PaintCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Ljavax/swing/JList;Ljava/lang/Object;IZZ)

OUTPUT: net.sourceforge.ganttproject.shape.PaintCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Ljavax/swing/JList;Ljava/lang/Object;int;boolean;boolean)

INPUT: 
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.ChartComponentBase$1.-init-(Lnet/sourceforge/ganttproject/ChartComponentBase;)

OUTPUT: 
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.ChartComponentBase$1.-init-(Lnet/sourceforge/ganttproject/ChartComponentBase;)

INPUT: 
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(III)

OUTPUT: 
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(int;int;int)

INPUT: 
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(Z)

OUTPUT: 
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(boolean)

The problem that I have is that even the B in ChartComponentBase ends up being replaced and I end up with "ChartComponentbytease"

The pattern should only work if there is a succession of capital letters(I or B or Z or J or S) to be replaced preceded by a semi colon 
Only the capital letters (I or B or Z or J or S) within parentheses should be replaced

I tried parsing  the string and separating the part within parentheses and using replaceAll then reassembling the string but it did not work:

```
                   methodname=methodname.substring(methodname.indexOf("("),methodname.indexOf(")")); 


                    methodname=methodname.replaceAll("B", "byte");
                    methodname=methodname.replaceAll("Z", "boolean");
                    methodname=methodname.replaceAll("I", "int");
                    methodname=methodname.replaceAll("J", "short");
                    methodname=methodname.replaceAll("S", "string");
```

I feel like using something along these lines might be more appropriate than using replaceAll:

```
          String regEx = "[BZIJS]";
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(method); 
          while (matcher.find()) {...}
```

Comment: *"I feel like using regex might be more appropriate than ReplaceAll"* The `replaceAll` arguments are regex, so you're saying that you want to use regex when you already are using regex.

Comment: I meant using  String shortmethod=method.substring(0, method.indexOf("(")); 
String regEx = "[A-Z]";  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(methodparam);
         while (matcher.find()) {...} instead of replaceAll

Comment: Regex won’t quite do it, due to the variable length look behinds required. You need to write a (simple) *parser* that moves along the input keeping track of where it is in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for the job.

Instead, write code like this:

```
String input = "net.sourceforge.ganttproject.shape.PaintCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Ljavax/swing/JList;Ljava/lang/Object;IZZ)\n" +
               "net.sourceforge.ganttproject.ChartComponentBase$1.-init-(Lnet/sourceforge/ganttproject/ChartComponentBase;)\n" +
               "net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(III)\n" +
               "net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-([[Z)\n";

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
int start = 0;
for (int i = 0; (i = input.indexOf('(', i)) != -1; i++) {
    buf.append(input.substring(start, ++i));
    int arrays = 0;
    ARGLOOP: for (;;) {
        start = i;
        switch (input.charAt(i)) {
            case ')':
                break ARGLOOP;
            case '[':
                arrays++;   i++;
                continue ARGLOOP;
            case 'L':
                if ((i = input.indexOf(';', i)) == -1)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unended object type at index " + start);
                buf.append(input.substring(start + 1, i).replace('/', '.'));
                break;
            case 'Z': buf.append("boolean"); break;
            case 'B': buf.append("byte");    break;
            case 'C': buf.append("char");    break;
            case 'S': buf.append("short");   break;
            case 'I': buf.append("int");     break;
            case 'J': buf.append("long");    break;
            case 'F': buf.append("float");   break;
            case 'D': buf.append("double");  break;
            case 'V': buf.append("void");    break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown type character at index " + i + ": " + input.charAt(i));
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays; j++)
            buf.append("[]");
        buf.append(';');
        arrays = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
String output = buf.append(input.substring(start)).toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.shape.PaintCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JList;java.lang.Object;int;boolean;boolean;)
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.ChartComponentBase$1.-init-(net.sourceforge.ganttproject.ChartComponentBase;)
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(int;int;int;)
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttCalendar.-init-(boolean[][];)
```

Answer (score 1):

AS state it from the answer before mine, it's a hard task to realise this kind of recursive problem with RegEx.

To give you hints and some guidlines I took this as an Example Input

```
net.sourceforge.ganttproject.shape.PaintCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Ljavax/swing/JList;Ljava/lang/Object;IZZ)
```

and applied this :

```
\(([^;]*);([^;]*);(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)\)
```

you can check it [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/4sAptr/3)

```
 Match 1
=========

Full match  81-123  `(Ljavax/swing/JList;Ljava/lang/Object;IZZ)` 
Group 1.    82-100  `Ljavax/swing/JList`<-----Group1 could be replaced as alias by $1
Group 2.    101-118 `Ljava/lang/Object`<-----Group2 could be replaced as alias by $2
Group 3.    119-120 `I`<-----Group3 could be replaced as alias by $3 
Group 4.    120-121 `Z`<-----Group4 could be replaced as alias by $4
Group 5.    121-122 `Z`<-----Group5 could be replaced as alias by $5
```

Then

```
swith(m.group(3))
{
                case 'I':
                    "($1;$2;int)";
                    break;
                case 'B':
                   "($1;$2;byte)";
                    break;
                  case 'Z':
                   "($1;$2;boolean)";
                    break;
                  case 'J':
                   "($1;$2;short)";
                    break;
                  case 'S':
                   "($1;$2;String)";
                    break;
                default:
                 break;
}
```

You must repeat this recursion and by shifting to the second parameter to the third an so one .....by m.group(4) and so one by m.group(5)...etc

Here I put a method that you can adapt for another problem that realy could be solved by RegEx.

```
public static String validate(String inputString) {
    String isDone = inputString;
    try {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([^;]*);([^;]*);(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)(B?Z?I?J?S?]*))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(isDone);

      while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Located at [" + m.group() + "] starting at " + m.start() + "and Ending at "
                           + (m.end() - 1));

      }
      isDone = isDone.replaceAll("(([^;]*);([^;]*);(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)(B?Z?I?J?S?]*)(B?Z?I?J?S?]*))", "($1;$2;XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ,etc)");
    }
    catch(PatternSyntaxException pse) {

      System.err.println("Bad Regex " + pse.getMessage());
      System.err.println("Description :" + pse.getDescription());
      System.err.println("Index : " + pse.getIndex());
      System.err.println("Incorrect Pattern :" + pse.getPattern());
    }
    return isDone;
  }
```

Where XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ,etc is equivalent to byte,short,String,int,boolean..etc which could be replace your aliases $3,$4,$5,$...  etc